# Custom non-recursive factorial function refuses further input after execution

Tags: python, python-idle, factorial

I am trying to write a simple `factorial` function in Python, but upon execution, this one merely does nothing and inherently crashes the console for some bizarre reason.

Please bear in mind that I only began coding with Python about a week ago, and am used to using other lower level OOP languages, so please excuse any obvious mistakes.

Here is my current function:

```
# initialise factorial function:
def factorial(n):
    i = 1 # initialise incrementing variable
    while i < n:
        n = n * i
        i = i + 1
    return n # return result
```

The function merely prints nothing and refuses any further input.

Comment: with each pass through the loop n becomes bigger and bigger, thus setting up an infinite loop (when is i supposed to catch up?). Perhaps you could introduce a variable other than n to contain the product you are trying to find.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I knew I'd missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this function: (works with n >= 0)

```
def factorial(n):
    r = 1
    i = 2
    while i <= n:
        # Use shorter version
        r *= i
        i += 1
    return r
```

Or (works with n > 0)

```
def factorial(n):
    i = n
    while i > 1:
        i -= 1
        n *= i
    return n
```

Comment: Perfect, will accept answer after timing delay has terminated.

Comment: The first one outputs `(n-1)!`. The second one gives an incorrect result for `0!`.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input("Enter a number "))
result=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if i<n:
        result=result*(i+1)
print("Factorial of {} is {}".format(n,result))
```

Comment: Hi @lohi try to explain your solution to give better responses.